# Executing formula from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a process that builds reports based upon dynamic SQL queries stored in tables.  When I originally wrote it as a proof-of-concept it was able to successfully work when using a cursor style process...was originally actually done as a script in the proof, using Do/While - the "proof" was moved to tSQL initially in the same format and successful, other than the fact that it ran like crap because it was iterating 1 record at a time.

### I rewrote the process to leverage the point of using SQL - mass select/manipulation of records...but I haven't been able to get the calculation grab to work in this manner and have just been using statically written case statements.

Tables:
Items list - just a friendly label for what each item is.
SourceQuery - nvarchar fields containing actual SQL select statements
Calculations - varchar fields containing data such as `DateAdd(m,-1,CalcDate)` and `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, CalcDate), 0)` and a lot of other calculations based upon other values.  (CalcDate is a select value which is going into the TempTable currently)

The dynamic execution takes the SourceQuery, builds, then executes it into a temp table:

```
DECLARE @SourceQuery Nvarchar(max)
create table #TempTable...
select distinct @SourceQuery=SourceQuery from vewTaskCombo where ....
Set @SourceQuery = 'Insert into #TempTable...' + @SourceQuery
Execute (@SourceQuery)
```

The above is doing the SourceQuery into the temp table but not currently doing anything with calculations - as mentioned that is currently done by an update statement using a CASE statement to decide which Date Calculation to use.

What I would like to do is eliminate the CASE statement and allow it to grab the calculation directly from the table.  When doing this as a single item iteration it was fine because we could assign the calculation to a variable.

The above is just a snippet of the pieces - there are several other table elements that are all joined together to create the query and decide the calculations.

Edit response:
the issue I am having is how to get the calculation from the table to execute as a statement. So for example if I inner join the calculation table in I can grab what type of calculation it should be (DateAdd....) but it is grabbing it only as a varchar and no longer able to execute it as calculation. Before because it was iterating 1 at a time the current calculation was grabbed into a variable and executed that way. But now because I am doing it all in bulk.  I can insert the formula into the temp table as another value but can't figure out how to get it to execute it as a calculation.

The goal is to execute the calculation that is stored in the table.  I can select the calculation into the temp table but can't figure out how to execute it as a calculation without putting it into a separate variable - and since there can be more than one calculation I can't just assign it to a single variable (without putting in a cursor to go through each calculation one at a time, which I am trying to avoid doing).

Currently the statically written case statements look something like:

```
Update #TempTable 
Set StartDate = CASE WHEN TaskThresholdID=2 then   
DateAdd(m,-1,CalcDate)
WHEN TaskThresholdID=4 then DateAdd(m,-1,CalcDate)
.
.
.
DueDate = CASE WHEN TaskThresholdID=2 then  DateAdd("D",4,CalcDate)
WHEN TaskThresholdID=4 then CalcDate
.
.
.
```

### The goal is to grab that calculation from the table and not have it statically written into the procedure.

And thank you LukStorms for code formatting edit.

Comment: You need to provide more detail about what it is you have now, plus what it is you are trying to do, along with a clear description of the problem you're having and what it is you need help with. I've read your post a couple of times, but cannot understand why you have apparent fragments of logic - why not just replicate the statements as many times as required to provide for all the options, and put them in a table with as many bit or descriptor fields for you to be able to identify the one to use in any given instance?

Comment: PS, you need to indent your SQL code with 4 spaces in order to make it appear formatted

Comment: John - the issue I am having is how to get the calculation from the table to execute as a statement.

So for example if I inner join the calculation table in I can grab what type of calculation it should be (DateAdd....) but it is grabbing it only as a varchar and no longer able to execute it as calculation.  

Before because it was iterating 1 at a time the current calculation was grabbed into a variable and executed that way.  But now because I am doing it all in bulk I can insert the formula into the temp table but can't figure out how to get it to execute it as a calculation.

Comment: It is a typo, the actual statement is Exec (@SourceQuery).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution to it after trying a few other ideas.  Initially tried using a more formalized equation, while we did eventually get that to work the problem was adding "30" or "31" days in translation for a month was too inaccurate.

What I ended up doing was building the dynamic queries into a table (#UpdateQuery_Temp) then using COALESCE in order to get those into a single query.  And finally EXECUTE that individual query.

```
Create Table #UpdateQuery_Temp (TaskThresholdID int, UpdateQuery varchar(max))
insert into #UpdateQuery_Temp
Select Distinct ThresholdID, ('update #TempTable set StartDate=' + StartCalculation + ',DueDate=' + DueCalculation + ' where ThresholdID=' + cast(ThresholdID as varchar(2)) + ' ') FROM #TempTable

DECLARE @UpdateQuery varchar(max)
SELECT @UpdateQuery = COALESCE(@UpdateQuery + ' ',' ') + UpdateQuery + ';'
FROM #UpdateQuery_Temp
EXECUTE (@UpdateQuery)
```

Using this format no matter how many combinations of Start/Due calculations there are it can dynamically grab those from the table and execute them.  The execution time on 13,000 records took a small hit of 0.01 seconds - production tables are a few million records but the time difference is small enough that it is worth the hit to get it back to being table driven.